# Using LEAD (or LAG) in conjunction with a JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server

A detail table needs to get column data from a header table, including data from previous and following header record.

I have tried various combinations using SELECT, JOIN, etc

I am too embarrassed to show you ;)

```
HEADER table

HEADERPK    TIMESTAMP               LOCATION
--------    --------------------    --------
1234        2019–05-22 12:00:00     ABC
3456        2019-08-14 21:30:00     XYZ
7890        2019-10-01 05:00:00     QRS




DETAIL table

DETAILPK    PART        HEADERPK
---------   ---------   --------
2222        ZZZ-100     1234
3333        ZZZ-100     3456
4444        ZZZ-100     7890
```

Expected Results (using the DETAIL table)

```
DETAILPK    PREV_LOCATION   PREV_TIMESTAMP      NEXT_LOCATION   NEXT_TIMESTAMP
--------    -------------   ------------------- -------------   -------------------
3333        ABC     2019–05-22 12:00:00         QRS             2019-10-01 05:00:00
```

The intent is that for a given DETAIL record, I can determine the timestamp and location for the previous and following HEADER records.

My thought has been to JOIN the tables using the HEADERPK, but I am unclear how, for each detail, to order the header records.

Comment: How are you defining "next" ?

Comment: Well doggone it, I inadvertently left out a component of the question.  To all responders, no need to provide any answers until I make the update.  Thank you to all who answered so quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a window function and a sub-query. I think the most readable way is to use a CTE with all the window functions:

```
WITH 
    adjacent_headers AS
    (
        SELECT
            headerpk,
            prev_headerpk = LAG(headerpk) OVER (ORDER BY headerpk),
            prev_ts = LAG([timestamp]) OVER (ORDER BY headerpk),
            prev_loc = LAG(location) OVER (ORDER BY headerpk),
            next_headerpk = LEAD(headerpk) OVER (ORDER BY headerpk),
            next_ts = LEAD([timestamp]) OVER (ORDER BY headerpk),
            next_loc = LEAD(location) OVER (ORDER BY headerpk)
        FROM header
    )
SELECT
    detail.detailpk,
    adjacent_headers.prev_loc,
    adjacent_headers.prev_ts,
    adjacent_headers.next_loc,
    adjacent_headers.next_ts
FROM detail
    INNER JOIN adjacent_headers ON
        adjacent_headers.headerpk = detail.headerpk
```

Note that this assumes you're defining "previous" and "next" header records by sorting on the Header ID column. If you want to only include details where the related header has both a previous and next record, you can add that to the `WHERE` clause of your final query.

Answer (score 0):

If you're saying that you want to use `lead` or `lag` inside `join`, you can't do that.  But if you just want to use them in the same sql statement, you can do this:

```
select      d.detailpk,
            prev_location = lead(h.location) over(order by h.timestamp desc),
            prev_timestamp = lead(h.timestamp) over(order by h.timestamp desc),
            next_location = lag(h.location) over(order by h.timestamp desc),
            next_timestamp = lag(h.timestamp) over(order by h.timestamp desc)
from        detail d
join        header h on d.headerpk = h.headerpk
order by    h.timestamp;
```

Now, if your real scenario has a lot of fields you need to grab the `lead` and `lag` items on, you can avoid so many `over` statements like this:

```
with

    offset as (

        select      *,
                    prev_headerPk = lead(headerpk) over(order by timestamp),
                    next_headerPk = lag(headerpk) over(order by timestamp)
        from        header

    )

    select      d.detailpk,
                prev_location = p.location,
                prev_timestamp = p.timestamp,
                next_location = n.location,
                next_timestamp = n.timestamp
    from        detail d
    left join   offset p on d.headerpk = p.prev_headerPk
    left join   offset n on d.headerpk = n.next_headerPk
```